# Does Express Profiler have a major effect on performance of SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I'm wondering does running Express Profiler against an SQL Express Server have a major impact on performance.  The versions of SQL Express I'm looking to run against are on 2008 and 2013.

This is the express profiler I'm using. http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/

Comment: Did you try it? The problem with asking about performance impact of 3rd party tools here is that (a) not everyone here has even heard of that tool (especially since SQL Server's own profiler is now free with Management Studio Express in SQL Server 2012 SP1), (b) those who have heard of it might not have done any performance testing, (c) those who have done performance testing have done so on completely different systems with different usage patterns and probably with completely different traces, and (d) most folks know to use server-side traces rather than graphical tools anyway.

Comment: @Aaron Didn't know that was now free, I'll try downloading it and see how I get on with it. Have you a link on how to use server-side traces?

Comment: You can [download Management Studio 2012 SP1 here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579). Plenty of articles on server-side trace vs. profiler, and why: [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2007/08/01/trace-profiler-test.aspx), [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/272/profiler-and-server-side-traces/), [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72363/), [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/sql-trace/observer-overhead-trace-extended-events)...

Comment: To get you started, Jonathan has some numbers on [**Measuring “Observer Overhead” of SQL Trace vs. Extended Events**](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/sql-trace/observer-overhead-trace-extended-events)

Answer (score -1):

Performance impact of expressprofiler is almost the same as of standard sql profiler and can be up to 25%

Comment: Any sources for that statement?

Comment: My expirience, observations, lab testing

Comment: @Locky your environment and OP's environment (workload, server spec, etc) will be totally different and to make a number (as you had --> 25%) will not be correct.

Comment: of course "it depends", but taking into account that ExpressProfiler supposed to use (but not limited to) with SqlExpress - "up to 25% performance degradation" is precise enough definition.